# What does "some hats wear men" mean?

Tags: meaning

In the movie  *Spider-Man: Homecoming* (2017), there is a scene where Peter and his friend Ned are in Aunt May's car before they go to Liz's party. Aunt May says this line to Ned:

> May: Ned, some hats wear men. You wear that hat.

I know she is complimenting Ned, but I don't understand why it is.
What does "some hats wear men" mean?

Comment: It's in the passive voice of **"Some men wear hats"** The man is doing the verb and in the passive **"Some hats wear men"** is the object being done by the verb. It means that *the hat is not chosen by men but by the hat itself*; it's a form of idiom. Similar to, **"I didn't choose the thug life; the thug life chose me"**

Comment: @aesking It's a reversal, surely; the passive voice would be "Some men are worn by their hats". I take it to mean that a very conspicuous hat worn by a self-effacing person seems to dominate their personality in the eyes of others.

Comment: @Kate no because that would mean "some hats wear men" would have to be "some hats *are worn by* men". Are worn is certainly a past participle in the passive mood, but one can quite simply turn into the passive by changing who/what is being done to the verb. Remember "some hats wear men" is idiomatic (also [parataxis](https://www.thoughtco.com/parataxis-grammar-and-prose-style-1691574/)) and therefore should not follow a formal expesssion in the passive // and changing the wording of the sentence that defeats the purpose of a parataxis is not recommended.